# Сортировка ORM Kohana

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Есть две модели

```
class Model_Model extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'models';

    protected $_primary_key = 'id';

    protected $_db_group = 'default';

}

class Model_Tyre extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'tyres';

    protected $_primary_key = 'id';

    protected $_db_group = 'default';

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'model' => array(
            'model' => 'model',
            'foreign_key' => 'model_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

Есть запрос к БД:

```
$tyre = ORM::factory('tyre')->order_by( )->find_all();
```

Что нужно вставить в `order_by`, что бы сортировка была по полю `model_rating` из таблицы `models`? Пробовал `model->model_rating`, не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, это делается так:

```
$tyre = ORM::factory('tyre')
     ->join('models','inner') // left, right?
     ->on('models.id','=','tyres.model_id')
     ->order_by('models.model_ratings', 'desc') // asc?
     ->find_all();
```

Мне самому такое решение не нравится, но оно работает.

P.S.: В `protected $_primary_key = 'id'` нет необходимости, так как `$_primary_key` по-умолчанию равен `'id'`. Это же касается и `$_table_name`.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает)

Answer (score 0):

```
$tyre = ORM::factory('tyre')->order_by('model_ratings','asc' )->find_all();
```

Comment: это поле (model_rating) находится в таблице models, а не в tyres